# UITableView works in 3.2 but no tableview methods are firing in 4.0 (simulator & device)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I just came across a situation where my implementation of a tableview is working in 3.2 but fails to fire any of the tableview methods in iOS 4. The view controller in question is defined as a UIViewController and is setup to adopt the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols, and I'm hooking the tableview up as the view's datasource and delegate via IB.

Definition in .h:

```
@interface FooViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,
    UITableViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITableView *itemTable;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *itemTable;
```

.m:

```
@synthesize itemTable;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView fired!");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection fired!");
    return 2;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

return cell;
}
```

This appears to work fine in < 4.0, but in 4 it just simply bypasses firing any of these methods. Am I by chance doing it incorrectly and being caught up by something being fixed in 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `dataSource` and `delegate` set for the `itemTable`? The rest of your code seems to look fine. Another question is why use the `UiViewController` instead of using the `UITableViewController`

I've been using the `UITableViewController` and it works quite well, and you can still just implement the simple basic methods you have implemented.

Comment: WRT datasource/delegate: yes, hooked up via IB.

More findings:
It appears it only *doesn't* work in iOS 4 when the file owner is pushed on the stack via presentModalViewController. When I push it via a navigation controller, it seems to work fine. I'm pushing via presentModalViewController because it is the screen that slides in for presenting in-app purchase stuff.

So the problem has now been refined - the tableView methods don't get called when the parent view controller is pushed via presentModalViewController. This appears to be where it 'broke' in iOS 4...or at least changed behavior.